# How can I reduce the TIme Complexity. of the python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, pandas, multiprocessing

I have 7000 CSV files that I want to do operation on. but the problem is that it takes to much time like it takes 13 seconds to process these files.
What I need to know is which operation take more time.

1. Opening and closing the files?
2. Reading data from these files?

I want to convert this program into multithreading or may be multiprocessing to achieve the goal.
What would you suggest?

1. MultiThreading in Python
2. Multiprocessing in Python
3. other

```
import time
import os
import sys
import threading
import concurrent.futures


import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')


no_of_files=0

def files_path(directory):
    global no_of_files
    file_path_list=[]
    for filename in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
        if filename.endswith(".csv"):
            no_of_files+=1
            file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            file_path_list.append(file_path)
    return file_path_list
      
    
def process_file(file_path):
    file=open(file_path,'r')
    lines = 0
    sum_of_lines=0
    number_of_characters=0
    for line in file:
        number_of_characters=len(line)+number_of_characters
        lines=lines+1
        sum_of_lines=sum_of_lines+1
        
    file.close()
    lines = ('{0:n}'.format(int(lines)))
    number_of_characters = '{0:n}'.format(int(number_of_characters))


    print(str(file_path.split("/")[2]))
    print("\t" + "|Number of lines : " + "\t" + "\t" + str(lines))
    print("\t" + "|Number of characters : " + "\t" + "\t" + str(number_of_characters))


    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s=time.time() 
    for i in range(320):
        directory = 'D:/Tickers/'
        all_files= files_path(directory)
        for file_path in all_files:
            process_file(file_path)
    e=time.time()
    print(f"{no_of_files} takes {e-s}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. Describe *what* the program is doing and *why* (that is, the purpose of the program).  Better descriptions lead to better reviews!  [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226)

Answer (score 1):

`multiprocessing` might be a desirable approach in your case:

You need to modify your `__main__` function to below:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = time.time()
    directory = 'D:/Tickers/'
    all_files = files_path(directory)
    
    pool_file_list = []
    for _ in range(320):
        pool_file_list.extend(all_files)
        
    pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
    pool.map(process_file, pool_file_list)
    
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
        
    e = time.time()
    print(f"{no_of_files} takes {e - s}")
```

Comment: Should i import some package in order to run the Pool FUnction?

Comment: `from multiprocessing import Pool`

Comment: Updated in the answer, too

Comment: can you please explain a little bit these lines it will help me a lot. thank you so much for your time

Comment: You are just splitting your tasks across multiple cores on your machine. So, say you have 8 cores; you would ideally see 8x improvement